# How to prove $\oint_{A}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$ mathematically and rigorously?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

How to prove $\oint_{A}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$ mathematically and rigorously?

This equation is called “Gauss's Law” in physics. I seek for a rigorous mathematical proof for it (my original physics textbook doesn't provide a rigorous proof).

Now, I want to describe my question in detail.

Let $\mathbf{r}=x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+z\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ be a vector in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$. $\mathbf{E}$ is function from $\mathbf{R}^{3}\backslash{\mathbf{0}}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ and $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\mathbf{r}|^{2}}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$. $A$ is an irregular closed surface enclosing $\mathbf{0}$. Prove $\oint_{A}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$.

Comment: Via Gauss' theorem is possible and using $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$. However, you'll encounter a delta "function". To make it rigorous in the math sense you need to consider it as a distribution instead

Comment: Deriving Gauss's law from Coulomb's law +Proof (without Dirac Delta)
in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law  (maybe helps)

Comment: I think there’s a misconception here, Gauss’s law is an axiom of electromagnetism, there is no proving it because it’s a physical thing. Electromagnetism is really just the study of the Maxwell field equations, of which gauss’s law is one of them, so you really take it as a given. If anything, you show that the electric field of a point charge is given by what you have using gauss’s law.

Comment: @Chris I would agree with you that Gauss’ law is an experimental (and so an axiom in our theory) but OP’s question can be phrased without ever talking about Gauss’ law. It is more so about given a certain explicit vector valued function, prove its flux over any (reasonable enough) surface enclosing the origin equals the constant $q/\epsilon_0$, independent of the surface of integration. Now this is certainly provable using the divergence theorem by “deforming the surface of integration” into a sphere where the calculation is obvious.

Comment: And unlike what the comments above say, for OP’s specific question, there’s no need to invoke distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain a rigorous proof by first obtaining the result for $\ A=RS^2 ,$ the surface of a sphere of radius $ R\ $ centred on the origin, and then using [Gauss's divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) to extend it to an arbitrary surface surrounding the origin. First
\begin{align}
\oint_{RS^2}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}&=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\oint_{RS^2}\frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}dA\\
&=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0R^2}\oint_{RS^2}dA\\
&=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ |\mathbf{r}|=R\ $ is constant on $\ RS^2\ ,$ and the surface area of a sphere of radius $\ R\ $ is $\ 4\pi R^2\ .$ Now suppose $\ A\ $ is any compact [rectifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set) surface surrounding the origin, and therefore at a positive minimum distance from it, and let $\ \delta\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\min_\limits{\mathbf{r}\in A}\frac{|\mathbf{r}|}{2}\ .$ Let $\ V\ $ be the set enclosed between the surfaces $\ A\ $ and $\ \delta S^2\ .$ Then, since $\ \mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=0\ $ throughout $\ V\ ,$ Gauss's theorem gives us
\begin{align}
0&=\iiint_V\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}\,dV\\
&=\oint_{\partial V}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}\\
&=\oint_{A\,\cup\,\delta S^2}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}\\
&=\oint_A\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}+\oint_{\delta S^2}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}\\
&=\oint_A\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ ,
\end{align}
the negative sign here arising from the fact that the outward normal to $\ \delta S^2\ $ as the boundary of $\ V\ $ is in the opposite direction to its outward normal as the boundary of a ball centred on the origin.